# PHP Soap client issue in importing schema from WSDL : Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing Schema: can't import schema from

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl, php-7

I am using Soap protocol with WSDL on server side. For some reason PHP is not able to import the schema. But the schema import links are opening in browser without any problem. The *schema links are https* links, but I have enabled openssl in PHP.

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php

$client = new SoapClient("https://domain:460/path/RemittanceRequest1.wsdl");
```

**Error**

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing Schema: can't import schema from 'https://domain:460/Service/mex2.xsd', unexpected 'targetNamespace'='http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/RMTService' in E:\xampp\htdocs\wsdl\GetCurrencyCodesReq.php:3
```

**PHP Version** - 7.0.4

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an imported xsd file ?

It's usually related to a mismatch between the attributes:  namespace from the `<import>` tag and the targetNamespace from the schema tag in the imported xsd file.

Comment: You can find the WSDL here:
https://royalexchange.co.in:460/RoyalMoneyCashnBankService/RemittanceRequest1.wsdl

Comment: Try to change schemaLocation value with only filename : "mex.xsd" for the first. According to the documentation [link](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_schema.asp)  This attribute has two values, separated by a space. The first value is the namespace to use. The second value is the location of the XML schema to use for that namespace

Comment: Can you please give an example. I didn't get that.

Comment: Replace `<xsd:import schemaLocation="https://royalexchange.co.in:460/RoyalMoneyCashnBankService/mex.xsd" namespace="http://tempuri.org/"/>` with `<xsd:import schemaLocation="https://royalexchange.co.in:460/RoyalMoneyCashnBankService mex.xsd" />`